# Detecting the triggering of AdSense Page-Level Anchors (on Mobile) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, anchor, ads, adsense

AdSense "Page-Level Anchors" are these small animated overlay Ads which appear at the bottom of your website on Mobile devices.

**The problem:** I need a way to DETECT when these Ads trigger, ideally using jQuery, and also when they are dismissed by the user.

Why is this important? Because I have an overlay of my own at the same position, and I want to dynamically reposition it above the Anchor Ad when it appears, and then reposition it back to its starting position when (or if) the Ad is dismissed by the user.

The parent element of these ads is an `<ins>` tag with a fixed ID (either '*aswift_4_anchor*', or '*aswift_5_anchor*').

The problem is that these TAGS are created Dynamically by Google's AdSense script, and so therefor let's say I use `$.(document).ready(function(){...$('#aswift_4_anchor') ...or... document.getElementById('aswift_4_anchor')});` to try and select them so I can read their CSS properties... this doesn't work because at the moment of `$.(document).ready()` the Anchor Ad hasn't shown up yet. And in fact the `<ins>` don't even exist yet, as they are dynamically appended to the DOM tree by the AdSense script. Let's say it triggers 5 or 10 seconds later...

I have tried experimenting with `$(document).addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){})` as the Anchor Ad uses a sliding animation from the bottom, so I figured that might be detected, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I never did... I think I just ended up not implementing that idea. It was a while ago so can't really recall all the specifics.